# How much is the current consumption of this sensor (tmp102)?

Tags: sensor, current, temperature

Here is the [data-sheet.](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/tmp102.pdf)

I just want to know how much time it takes to measure the temperature and how much current it consumes. I struggle when trying to find such info in the data-sheet so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at Figure 3, you'll see that conversion time is a function of both supply voltage and temperature, ranging from 26 ms to 30 ms.

Looking at the Electrical Specifications on page 3, under Power Supply, the power consumption with the bus inactive is less than 0.5 µA in shutdown mode, and up to 10 µA otherwise. However, note that the bus interface draws power in proportion to the activity on the bus, independent of the mode of the sensor, and this can add up to an additional 80 µA at high bus speeds (3.4 MHz).

Comment: So if I have an average of 28ms operating time and a consumption of 10uA and I take only one measurement per minute that means: 0.5u *(59.972/60) + 10uA*(0.028/60)= 29.99uA and to calculate consumption in a day: 24h * 29.99uA = 719.776uAh. Is that right?

Comment: I would probably round it up to 30 uA average current, in order to allow for the bus activity associated with each measurement, and call it 720 uAh per day.

Comment: one more question: when you have the sensor tied up a sensor node which is in sleep mode, does the bus consume current of 0.5uA?

Comment: I would think so. The 0.5 uA represents the minimum static consumption of the device.